# How to search/find multiple matches with mongodb in a node express app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make a search bar for my website which finds a street name and number.

Here is the problem. I have this schema:

```
{_id: 0013dsasda2932090,Street: "11 Exemple Street"}

{_id: 0013293asfsad2090,Street: "33 Exemple Street"}

{_id: 001329asdfasf32090,Street: "22 Exemple Blvd"}
```

When I search for the name "Exemple Street" it should return only "11 Exemple Street"  and  "33 Exemple Street"   not all the Exemple's because the word 'Exemple'.

Also I'm using a variable instead of a String.
How do I do that condition with mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

You can use $regex to do this.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Exemple :

```
db.streets.find({"Street" : { $regex : /Exemple Street/ }})
```